# Solid State Drive for PS4

Tags: gaming, ssd, video-game-console

I'm converting my Playstation 4 to a SSD and I'm unsure which drive would be best for this. I don't have alot of knowledge about these drives and I couldn't find any reviews about them. Essentially, I'm looking for faster game boots and not really worried about storage. The 2 that I'm debating between are as follows:

http://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=179_1229_1088&item_id=080111

OR

http://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=179_1229_1088&item_id=094585

Some explanation as to which would be best is much appreciated.

TYIA

Comment: Go for the fast read/write speed.

Comment: So out of those 2, the Samsung Evo (first link) would be the best?

Comment: They are both pretty comparable to each other, so either one would be alright.  Maybe try googling to see what others have used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as raw speed is concerned, the **Samsung EVO** is the way to go. The drives themselves are very reliable and have the faster **read (540mb/s)** and **write (520mb/s)** speeds.

I myself have a **Samsung EVO** and it works flawlessly in my **PC**. In my **PS4**... well I haven't tried it in there.

Some people claim its a **bad idea**, and that you won't see any difference in speed with the use of an **SSD** due to hardware limitations of the PS4; they claim that an **SSHD** is a better call for this sort of upgrade. You can read about that [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/2d2z85/has_anyone_used_the_new_samsung_850_pro_ssd_with/).

On the other hand, this gentlemen [here](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2016-is-it-worth-upgrading-your-ps4-with-an-ssd) saw a **large difference** in speed with *some games* (check out the tables he created with load time comparisons).

My advice would be: if you see value in the upgrade to an SSD based on the sources I've provided, go for it.

If you were expecting an SSD to cut your load times in half across the board, either temper your expectations, or save some money and get yourself an SSHD.

Comment: I ended up going with the Samsung Evo 850. I looked up more benchmark tests and it seems like a good idea. I feel my PS4 lags with load times on certain games and I'm inpatient. Thank you for the sources, they helped

Comment: @BrandonMuise I have one of these -  a lovely drive! However, on a PS4, maybe sticking with an HDD is the better choice.